# How to create correct resource file path in a java jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Sitting here with a bigger java project (for a first year software student) having some troubles creating the correct file path to resources.

I right now have files in the form of .txt, .png, .jpg, and a .gif.

Right now i use paths like this to find a text file:

```
File userFile = new File("Source Code/files/users.txt");
```

Or paths like this to create an image loaded in my FX code:

```
File logoPath = new File("Source code/files/graphics/Streamy_logo.png");
Image logoImage = new Image(logoPath.toURI().toString());
logo.setImage(logoImage);
```

This works fine in my IDE (IntelliJ), however it doesn't work when i create the project as a Jar file.
I think is has to do with the "source code" directory not created in the jar-file, which makes sense now.

Tried to read different subjects, but it seems a bit different if i should use a getResources-method, set a resourceStream or something else.

Can anybody please help me with this.
Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not different. Using `File` will never work when the resources are in a jar.

Comment: What should i use instead?

Comment: Always use Class.getResource.  If it doesn’t work, make sure your project packages everything in `files` in your .jar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/loading-image-resource here is good examples

Answer (score 0):

You can't load files like that in .jar files here's an example on how to read BufferedImages.
But first, make sure you have marked the resource folder as a resource folder in IntelliJ by right-clicking the folder in the project view and going down to "Mark directory as" and checking resource root.

```
    BufferedImage exampleBlock = null;
    try {
        exampleBlock = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("exampleBlock.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

By using this method of getting files all your files will be implemented into the .jar file and you can use them by calling their file name + extension

Answer (score 0):

For maven or gradle projects, that respects maven directories convention you can simply use

```
getClass().getResource("/your_file_located_in_src_main_resources.extension").getPath()
```